# Delete leading comma

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am reading info from a sqlite database to a .csv file. I am able to get the file to build, but each new line starts with a ",". I have done some android programming, but not much ios. I am thinking that the issue is componentsJoinedByString:@"," since it joins everything together, but I am not sure how to get rid of the "," at the beginning of each new line using this. Is there another way to join them to write to a csv file or a way to get rid of the first comma?

```
NSMutableArray *exportBike = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MemberDB.sql"];

FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];

[database open];

FMResultSet *resultsBike = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM bike"];

while([resultsBike next]) {

    NSString *name = [resultsBike stringForColumn:@"name"];
    NSInteger stage1HR  = [resultsBike intForColumn:@"stage1HR"];
    NSInteger stage1BP = [resultsBike intForColumn:@"stage1BP"];
    NSInteger stage2HR = [resultsBike intForColumn:@"stage2HR"];
    NSInteger stage2BP = [resultsBike intForColumn:@"stage2BP"];
    NSInteger stage3HR  = [resultsBike intForColumn:@"stage3HR"];
    NSInteger stage3BP = [resultsBike intForColumn:@"stage3BP"];
    NSInteger stage4HR  = [resultsBike intForColumn:@"stage4HR"];
    NSInteger stage4BP = [resultsBike intForColumn:@"stage4BP"];
    NSInteger stage5HR  = [resultsBike intForColumn:@"stage5HR"];
    NSInteger stage5BP = [resultsBike intForColumn:@"stage5BP"];
    NSInteger stage6HR  = [resultsBike intForColumn:@"stage6HR"];
    NSInteger stage6BP = [resultsBike intForColumn:@"stage6BP"];
    NSInteger stage7HR  = [resultsBike intForColumn:@"stage7HR"];
    NSInteger stage7BP = [resultsBike intForColumn:@"stage7BP"];
    NSInteger recoveryHR = [resultsBike intForColumn:@"recoveryHR"];

    NSLog(@"%@,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",name, stage1HR, stage1BP, stage2HR, stage2BP, stage3HR, stage3BP, stage4HR, stage4BP, stage5HR, stage5BP, stage6HR, stage6BP, stage7HR, stage7BP, recoveryHR);

    [exportBike addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d""\n",name, stage1HR, stage1BP, stage2HR, stage2BP, stage3HR, stage3BP, stage4HR, stage4BP, stage5HR, stage5BP, stage6HR, stage6BP, stage7HR, stage7BP, recoveryHR]];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *savePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    savePath = [savePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bike.csv"];

    [[exportBike componentsJoinedByString:@","] writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Comment: `exportBike` has only one object in it? Or is the above code in a for loop? From the above code you can just write the string `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d""\n",name, stage1HR, stage1BP, stage2HR, stage2BP, stage3HR, stage3BP, stage4HR, stage4BP, stage5HR, stage5BP, stage6HR, stage6BP, stage7HR, stage7BP, recoveryHR]` to file. You dont need an array.

Comment: @ ACB. I posted the whole code I am using to get the info from the db to populate the csv. I am not even sure if this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: I think you are still missing the closing bracket. Ideally the above code should work fine. `componentsJoinedByString` shouldn't add a comma at the beginning if you dont have any empty string in `exportBike` array.

Comment: @ ACB. I shouldn't have any empty string, everything populates with something. The closing bracket is there in Xcode, it got cut off when I posted it here. The output looks like this in the csv. The next row always has a comma in front. It does start on a new line though.                           Fake Account,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,Test numbers,120,176,120,178,126,178,126,182,132,182,132,182,144,182,126

Comment: You should try it like this, `[[exportBike componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"]` and remove the `"\n"` at the end of the addObject string line. Check it.

Comment: @ ACB. That was it, thank you so much! I knew it had to be something simple I missed. Put it in an answer so I can accept it please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
[exportBike addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d""\n",name, stage1HR, stage1BP, stage2HR, stage2BP, stage3HR, stage3BP, stage4HR, stage4BP, stage5HR, stage5BP, stage6HR, stage6BP, stage7HR, stage7BP, recoveryHR]];

[[exportBike componentsJoinedByString:@","] writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

to

```
[exportBike addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",name, stage1HR, stage1BP, stage2HR, stage2BP, stage3HR, stage3BP, stage4HR, stage4BP, stage5HR, stage5BP, stage6HR, stage6BP, stage7HR, stage7BP, recoveryHR]];

[[exportBike componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"] writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Instead of `","` use `"\n"` in `componentsJoinedByString` method and in `addObject` line remove the `"\n"` at the end.

As Martin mentioned below, another option is to keep the new line character in `addObject` line and use `[exportBike componentsJoinedByString:@""]`. This will add a new line character at the end of the file.

Comment: Or: keep the newline in `addObject`, and use `componentsJoinedByString:@""`. Then the last line in the output file is also newline terminated.

Comment: @MartinR, Good suggestion. But I wasn't sure if he needs a newline at the end of the file.